# Error: Object of type MissingPermissions is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py, embed

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=maincolour)
    embed.title = "**Error**"
    embed.description = error
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

When I run and put a command with an error or something, I want it to send back the embed but all it says in the logs is **Object of type MissingPermissions is not JSON serializable** on the last line of the script above. Please may someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `embed.description = error` with `embed.description = str(error)`
(print `type(error)` if you want to get a better understanding)

Comment: Oh my, I am really dumb that I couldn't solve this simple error. Thank you for contribution of telling me how to fix this, means alot! +1

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, please mark it as "accepted". Happy coding!